# Difference between typename parameter pack and auto parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Suppose I have this 2 definitions.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct S{};

template<auto... Ts>
struct S{};
```

What's the difference between this 2 definitions?
When we should opt for the one or another?

Comment: `template<auto> struct S` is only available since C++17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates have 3 kinds of [parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

1. Template *type* parameters
2. Template *non-type* parameters
3. Template *template* parameters

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct S{};
```

Here `Ts` is a pack of *type* parameters. It accepts data *types* like in `S<int, long>`.

```
template<auto... Ts>
struct S{};
```

Here `Ts` is a pack of *non-type* parameters with a *placeholder* type. It accepts *values* like in `S<12, 34L>`.

`auto` allows mixing of values of different types.

```
template<int... Ts>
struct S{};
```

This is similar, but all values are of fixed type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

They have different purpose, the former allows

```
S<int, char, float> s;
```

the later (only available since C++17) allows

```
S<42, '*', 42U> s;
```